# Increased RAM, Worse Performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, memory

Setup:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1
- 240GB RAM
- TempDB is 8x16GB data files w/out auto-grow (128GB total)
- Physical/Stand-alone Server

This server is used for ETL processing. We just installed more RAM in this server for a total of 240GB RAM. SQL Server services are the only real things running.

The memory shows up fine in the BIOS, OpenManage and Windows.

If I configure SQL Server to use a Min/Max of 70/100GB memory, we have no issues. However, once I increase that to 120/150GB, I get the following error when I run one of our ETL processes:

> Could not allocate space for object '<temporary system object:
>   422234507706368>' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY'
>   filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files,
>   dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the
>   filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the
>   filegroup. (Msg 1105, State 2, Procedure Unknown, Line 1)

We have never run into this issue prior to changing the memory configuration. After re-configuring back to the original 70/100GB, we do not receive this error.

Things I've tried:

1. Set the TempDB data files to auto-grow. This simply results in the files auto-growing until disk-capacity is reached and then fails.
2. Add more TempDB data files. Same error as shown.
3. Increase the TempDB size to 8x32GB (256GB total)

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this problem.

Comment: Is your memory balanced across NUMA nodes? How about your processors? Does the SQL Server log show how many CPUs are in use during startup?

Comment: What are you using for the ETL processes?  SSIS or some similar tool?  If it is a tool outside of SQL Server, are you running it on the same server as your SQL Server instance?

Comment: That's a good point @Mike, if the ETL process is unable to grab enough memory to do its thing, because SQL Server is using too much, then it might have to push work to tempdb.

Comment: The ETL process is all native SQL (stored procs, etc.) - no SSIS involved. @AaronBertrand, I'm not familiar w/ NUMA configuration - I'm reading up on it now. Is there a simple way to find out the answer to your first question? I see multiple nodes in dm_os_memory_clerks, but that just tells me that there are multiple NUMA nodes present right?

Comment: Here's a good starter to monitoring tempdb usage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029(v=SQL.105).aspx.  This should give you an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Stupid question: why do you have TempDB smaller than the actual RAM size? I always saw TempDB as an extension that's bigger (and slower) than actual RAM. I admit I never had the problem of making the TempDB smaller than available RAM. Sorry if it's too stupid :-).

Comment: Have you done any analysis of what's actually running when you're TempDB is actually expanding?  A simple sp_who2/sp_whoisactive?  It sounds to me like you've got some long running transactions that could be better managed, but difficult to tell.  Personally, I wouldn't get to attached to the memory change but look first at the code and see if that is running properly.

Comment: I'm doing some research/testing now - thanks all for the help. @MikeFal, I know the point at which it fails, but the memory increase is the only actual change that makes it go from success to fail. I've run the same exact process (w/ same exact data) on a box w/ 8GB RAM and a 32GB tempdb and it runs successfully (in the same amt of time)

Comment: I would look to see if the ETL process uses different query plans before/after the memory setting change. It could be doing something very different behind the scenes.

Comment: Is it possible that now that have the ram SQL is grabbing up more and then dumping more into tempDB then tempdb can handle?

Comment: Did you see where your Tempdb is located? Like c drive and page file is growing large etc? Just a thought.

Comment: During overnight testing w/ increased memory (120/150), I continued to get the same error. While the process was running, I polled the dm_db_file_space_usage dmv and found that it was filling up on internal object pages until it was at capacity. When the memory is configured at the lower end (70/100), it basically doesn't touch tempdb at all. Thoughts?

Comment: Can we get eyeballs on the execution plans please? Quite a few of us are intrigued with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your help.

After pouring through some execution plans, it turns out there is a JOIN that is being processed differently based on the amount of RAM available. With less RAM it evaluates it with a Hash; with more RAM, it uses a series of Merge Joins.

So basically it came down to poorly written T-SQL, which I am presently refactoring.

Comment: That's quite counter intuitive because a hash join requires a memory grant whereas the merge doesn't. Is there an additional sort operation to support the merge join?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question, just some code I didn't want to post in a comment. To see the balance of your schedulers and memory across NUMA nodes (and also to see if any nodes are not visible online):

```
SELECT 
  parent_node_id, 
  [status],
  AVG(current_tasks_count) AS avg_tasks_count, 
  AVG(load_factor) AS avg_load_factor,
  scheduler_count = COUNT(*)
FROM sys.dm_os_schedulers
GROUP BY parent_node_id, [status];

SELECT 
  memory_node_id, 
  name, 
  SUM(single_pages_kb + multi_pages_kb) AS memory_kb
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
GROUP BY memory_node_id, name;
```

(In SQL Server 2012, the last `SUM` should be `SUM(pages_kb)` since there are no longer  separate single- and multi-page allocators.)